# g++ cannot open output file ..\..\..\native\win32\native.dll: No such file or directory

Tags: java, dll, g++, native

```
REM Create the header with javac -h . ClassName.java
REM Remember to set your JAVA_HOME env var
g++ -c -I "%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I "%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.cpp -o com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.o
g++ -c -I "%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I "%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" com_baeldung_jni_ExampleParametersJNI.cpp -o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleParametersJNI.o
g++ -c -I "%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I "%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" com_baeldung_jni_ExampleObjectsJNI.cpp -o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleObjectsJNI.o
g++ -shared -o ..\..\..\native\win32\native.dll com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleParametersJNI.o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleObjectsJNI.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```

Output :

```
D:\work\git\project\tutorials-master\java-native\src\main\cpp>REM Create the header with javac -h . ClassName.java 

D:\work\git\project\tutorials-master\java-native\src\main\cpp>REM Remember to set your JAVA_HOME env var 

D:\work\git\project\tutorials-master\java-native\src\main\cpp>g++ -c -I "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\include" -I "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\include\win32" com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.cpp -o com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.o 

D:\work\git\project\tutorials-master\java-native\src\main\cpp>g++ -c -I "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\include" -I "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\include\win32" com_baeldung_jni_ExampleParametersJNI.cpp -o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleParametersJNI.o 

D:\work\git\project\tutorials-master\java-native\src\main\cpp>g++ -c -I "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\include" -I "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\include\win32" com_baeldung_jni_ExampleObjectsJNI.cpp -o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleObjectsJNI.o 

D:\work\git\project\tutorials-master\java-native\src\main\cpp>g++ -shared -o ..\..\..\native\win32\native.dll com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleParametersJNI.o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleObjectsJNI.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias 
**d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file ..\..\..\native\win32\native.dll: No such file or directory**
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmZik.png)

What's wrong?

Comment: path is wrong now update:g++ -shared -o d:\MinGW\bin\native.dll com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleParametersJNI.o com_baeldung_jni_ExampleObjectsJNI.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Make sure to create the folder ***..\..\..\native\win32*** prior that command.

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you, now is ok. g++ -shared -o "D:\Program Files\mingw64\bin\native.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, *GCC* (or *G++*) needs the output (might also apply to others: dump, auxiliary, ...) directory to exist<sup>*******</sup>.
By default, the output directory is *CWD* (***.***), which exists (in most cases).

Here's a dummy examle.

*sample.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("Dummy text\n");
    return 0;
}
```

> ```bash
> (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q073923282]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> sample.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> OUT_DIR=.
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o ${OUT_DIR}/sample.out sample.c
> [064bit prompt]> ./sample.out
> Dummy text
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> OUT_DIR=inner0
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o ${OUT_DIR}/sample.out sample.c
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file inner0/sample.out: No such file or directory
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> [064bit prompt]> mkdir -p ${OUT_DIR}
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o ${OUT_DIR}/sample.out sample.c
> [064bit prompt]> ./inner0/sample.out
> Dummy text
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> OUT_DIR=inner1/inner11
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o ${OUT_DIR}/sample.out sample.c
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file inner1/inner11/sample.out: No such file or directory
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> [064bit prompt]> mkdir inner1
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o ${OUT_DIR}/sample.out sample.c
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file inner1/inner11/sample.out: No such file or directory
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> [064bit prompt]> mkdir -p ${OUT_DIR}
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o ${OUT_DIR}/sample.out sample.c
> [064bit prompt]> ./inner1/inner11/sample.out
> Dummy text
> ```

[[GNU.GCC]: Options Controlling the Kind of Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) (*-o file* section) doesn't mention anything about this (which makes it strange, as *GCC* is well documented).
Also, the error message suggest otherwise:

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file inner0/sample.out: No such file or directory
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Going further (passing ***-v*** (verbose) option to *GCC*):

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -v -o inexistent/sample.out sample.c
> Using built-in specs.
> COLLECT_GCC=gcc
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
> OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
> OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
> Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
> Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu 
> --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
> Thread model: posix
> gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'inexistent/sample.out' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu sample.c -quiet -dumpbase sample.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase sample -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccjdCTrC.s
> GNU C17 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
>         compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP
>
> GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
>  /usr/local/include
>  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
>  /usr/include
> End of search list.
> GNU C17 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
>         compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP
>
> GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
> Compiler executable checksum: c0c95c0b4209efec1c1892d5ff24030b
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'inexistent/sample.out' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
>  as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccP79PwB.o /tmp/ccjdCTrC.s
> GNU assembler version 2.34 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
> COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
> LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'inexistent/sample.out' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc3Q3S6A.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o inexistent/sample.out /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. /tmp/ccP79PwB.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --po
> p-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file inexistent/sample.out: No such file or directory
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

It becomes obvious that **not *GCC* is having trouble creating the output directory, but the *GNU Linker*** ([[Man7]: LD(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html)) which *GCC* invokes under the hood (other linkers might behave differently).

As a side note, not only the linker is experiencing this issue, but also the preprocessor, compiler, assembler - which is visible by passing to *GCC* **one of** ***-E***, ***-S***, ***-c*** flags.

I've browsed a bit *LD*'s documentation, but I couldn't find a way to make it create the intermediary directories.

**The fix** (workaround) **is simple: create the directory** (`mkdir -p`) **before invoking *GCC* (G++)**.
It's a common practice (which is most visible inside *Makefile*s).